# USB DAC Causes USB Initialization Error

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, motherboard

I am using a "Fulla Schiit" USB DAC on a Windows 10 64-bit PC with an MSI Z170a motherboard.

Everything normally works fine but my power went down this morning and after turning on my PC I found there was no sound out of my headphones.

In my playback devices "Realtek Digital Output" was selected and the DAC wasn't shown.

n my device manager, it was shown as a device with a port reset failure, so I uninstalled it and rebooted my PC.

After rebooting my PC my motherboard got stuck on the error code "9C" which is a USB initialization error, as soon as I unplugged the DAC the computer continued to boot fine.

When I plug the DAC back in windows doesn't seem to recognize any device, however, it is powered as I can hear a noise in the headphones as it's plugged in.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a different cable? You can also search for a solution on this Schiit FAQ page.

Comment: I did use a different cable, same problem. I decided I was going to reorganize the cables behind my desk as I made a mess of them trying to troubleshoot this anyway, and once everything was unplugged I turned the computer on with solely a keyboard/mouse, then started plugging in everything one by one with the DAC first and it is working again, and still works on restart. I am unsure as to why the error occurred or why this solution works but it's a past issue now and I'm not all that interested in trying to recreate the problem to find out.